# Hosting static site from netlify load my script and styles two times

Tags: html, performance, netlify

I'm switching from Cloudflare + digital ocean to Netlify, but I have a small problem here. If you visit https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190309_BB_24284bd2d147340e582d931c3fba820/1/details/#step1_request8 you will see that when I'm hosting site from netlify, my site is loading main.js two times just like style.css. Is there something that I'm missing or? Here is scope from cloudflare + digital ocean https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190309_BA_33ef74c2cb20fa499c2c88711cd75c2/

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the page in the browser while you do a fresh reload of the page. Go to the Network section and you should see who's the culprit.

This is caused by your service worker setup doing duplicate cache loads.
You can see the service worker is getting the asset because the page is requesting the asset, then the service worker is fetching it again.

[image]